# QT libs as framework in Mac app

Tags: macos, frameworks, qt-creator, dyld

I use QT Creator, and when I build App, then the App is running, and i have no problem on my machine.
But, when I send my App my other Mac, I got error:

> Dyld Error Message:
>    Library not loaded:  /Users/MyDevUsername/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/4/QtOpenGL
>    Referenced from: /Users/OtherMachineUsername/Desktop/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp
>    Reason: image not found

I know, that I do not have QT as a framework in my app resource folder. I don't know how to compile my app, to make QT Lib, exist as an in app fremework.

Comment: Have you looked at the export options, there must be a method to package all the libraries connected with your app automatically.

Comment: I'm not that good with QT Creator to know where libs import is. I can't find it.